# How to compute the determinant of a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, toeplitz-matrices, faq

How to show that the determinant of the following $(n\times n)$ matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
2 & 5 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 5 & 2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots& \vdots& \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 2 & 5 & 2 \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 2 & 5
\end{pmatrix}$$

is equal to $\frac13(4^{n+1}-1)$?

---

More generally:

> How does one compute the determinant of the following [tridiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix) (where the three diagonals are constant)?
>
> $$M_n(a,b,c) = \begin{pmatrix}
> a & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
> c & a & b & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
> 0 & c & a & b & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
> \vdots & \vdots& \vdots& \vdots & \vdots& \vdots & \vdots \\
> 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & c & a & b \\
> 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & c & a
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Here $a,b,c$ can be taken to be real numbers, or complex numbers.

In other words, the matrix $M_n(a,b,c) = (m_{ij})_{1 \le i,j \le n}$ is such that
$$m_{ij} = \begin{cases}
a & i = j, \\
b & i = j - 1, \\
c & i = j + 1, \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

There does not seem to be an easy pattern to use induction: the matrix is not a diagonal [block matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) of the type $M = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} A & C \\ 0 & B \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ (where we could use $\det(M) = \det(A) \det(B)$ for the induction step), and there are no lines or columns with only one nonzero entry, so [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) gets complicated quickly.

Is there a general pattern that one could use? Or is the answer only known on a case-by-case basis? It's possible to compute the determinant by hand for small $n$:

$$\begin{align}
\det(M_1(a,b,c)) & = \begin{vmatrix} a \end{vmatrix} = a  \\
\det(M_2(a,b,c)) & = \begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & a \end{vmatrix} = a^2 - bc \\
\det(M_3(a,b,c)) & = \begin{vmatrix} a & b & 0 \\ c & a & b \\ 0 & c & a \end{vmatrix} = a^3 - 2abc
\end{align}$$

But there is no readily apparent pattern and the computation becomes very difficult when $n$ gets large.

Comment: I would suggest induction. It's going to be a little fiddly though.

Comment: Induction would work using [block determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices).

Comment: A more general case, where the diagonals aren't constant, is discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575748/determinant-of-symmetric-tridiagonal-matrices).

Comment: The determinant of such a matrix is sometimes called a [(generalized) continuant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuant_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 34):

We will generalize Calvin Lin's answer a bit. Let
$$A_n = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ c & a & b & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 0 & c & a & b & \cdots & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \cdots & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & a & b\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & c & a \end{bmatrix}.$$

We then have, by using [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) twice,
$$\det(A_n) = a \det(A_{n-1}) - bc \det(A_{n-2}).$$

Calling $\det(A_n) = d_n$ we have the following [linear homogeneous recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients):
$$d_n = a d_{n-1} - bc d_{n-2}.$$

The characteristic equation is
$$\begin{align}
x^2 - ax + bc = 0 & \implies \left(x - \frac{a}2 \right)^2 - \left(\frac{a}2 \right)^2 + bc = 0 \\
& \implies x = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2-4bc}}2.
\end{align}$$

(This assumes a square roots exist. It's always the case in $\mathbb{C}$.)

### Case 1: $a^2 - 4bc \neq 0$

In this case the characteristic polynomial has two distinct roots, so we have (for some constants $k_1$, $k_2$): $$d_n = k_1 \left( \dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2-4bc}}2\right)^n + k_2 \left( \dfrac{a - \sqrt{a^2-4bc}}2\right)^n.$$

We have $d_1 = a$ and $d_2 = a^2 - bc$. We then get that $d_0 = 1$. Hence,
$$k_1 + k_2 = 1.$$
$$a (k_1 + k_2) + (k_1 - k_2)\sqrt{a^2-4bc} = 2a \implies k_1 - k_2 = \dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-4bc}}.$$

Hence,
$$\begin{align}
k_1 & = \dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2-4bc}}{2\sqrt{a^2-4bc}}, & k_2 & = -\dfrac{a-\sqrt{a^2-4bc}}{2\sqrt{a^2-4bc}}
\end{align}$$

And finally:
$$\color{red}{\det(A_n) = \dfrac1{\sqrt{a^2-4bc}} \left( \left( \dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2-4bc}}2\right)^{n+1} - \left( \dfrac{a - \sqrt{a^2-4bc}}2\right)^{n+1}\right)}.$$

> Plug in $a = 5$ and $b=c=2$ ($a^2 - 4 bc \neq 0$), to get
>   $$\det(A_n) = \frac{1}{3} ( 4^{n+1} - 1)$$

### Case 2: $a^2 - 4bc = 0$

If the characteristic polynomial has a double root $x = a/2$, there exist constants $k_1$, $k_2$ such that:
$$d_n = (k_1 + k_2 n) \bigl(\frac{a}{2}\bigr)^n.$$

The initial conditions are $d_0 = 1$ and $d_1 = a$, thus:
$$\begin{align}
k_1 & = 1 & (k_1 + k_2) a = 2a
\end{align}$$

If $a = 0$, then $4bc = a^2$ implies either $b$ or $c$ is zero, and $d_n = 0$ for $n \ge 1$. Otherwise $$(k_1 + k_2) a = 2a \implies k_1 + k_2 = 2 \implies k_2 = 1.$$
And finally:
$$\color{red}{\det(A_n) = (n+1) \bigl(\frac{a}{2}\bigr)^n}.$$

Comment: For some reason, this is my first time seeing the off diagonal elements being different, though it clearly doesn't change anything in the proof.

Comment: Note that the recurrence relation in this answer is always valid, but the final answer only is when $a^2\neq 4bc$, so that is does not apply for instance to the special case of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/995779/18880).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It's been corrected. (I also reformatted the whole answer, the OP is a deleted account anyway...)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I don't understand why you derive $d_0$. Is it possible to solve the problem using only $d_1$ and $d_2$? (so computing $d_0$ would be a "trick" to ease the algebra) or is there something deeper?

Answer (score 15):

Let $M_n$ be the $n \times n$ matrix. Calculate the determinant by expanding along the first row and then by the second column, we get $ Det(M_n) = 5 Det(M_{n-1} ) - 4 Det(M_{n-2})$.

Let $Det(M_n) = D_n$, so $D_n$ satisfies the recurrence relation $D_n - 5 D_{n-1} + 4 D_{n-2} = 0$, with initial values $D_0 = 1, D_1 = 5$. The characteristic equation $x^2 - 5x + 4$ has roots $x= 4, 1$, so the solution has form $A4^n + B1^n$. Plugging in the initial values, we get $A= \frac {4}{3}, B= -\frac {1}{3}$, which yields the value $D_n = \frac {1}{3} (4^{n+1} - 1)$.

---

$D_0 = 1$ because it is the empty product, which by definition has the value 1. If you do not like to use $D_0 = 1$, you can just calculate $D_1 = 5$ and $D_2 = 5 \times 5 - 2 \times 2 = 21$ and then find the values of $A, B$.

Answer (score 6):

Your determinant is equal to
$$
2^n\det\begin{bmatrix}2x & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 1 & 2x & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 2x & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &\vdots\\ 0 & 
\cdots & 0 & 1 & 2x & 1 & 0\\ 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2x & 1\\ 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2x\end{bmatrix}=:2^nD_n(x),
$$
with $x=5/4$.  As in Calvin Lin's answer, $D_n(x)$ satisfies a recurrence, namely $D_n(x)=2xD_{n-1}(x)-D_{n-2}(x)$, which can be obtained by expanding $D_n(x)$ by minors on its first row and then expanding the $(n-1)$-by-$(n-1)$ determinant one gets in the second term by minors on its first column.  This is the defining recurrence for the [Chebyshev polynomials of the first and second kinds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials), which are denoted $T_n(x)$ and $U_n(x)$.  Furthermore, $U_0(x)=1=D_0(x)$ and $U_1(x)=2x=D_1(x)$.  So $D_n(x)=U_n(x)$.

The Chebyshev Polynomials are related to expansions of trigonometric or hyperbolic functions.  In the case of polynomials of the second kind,
$$
\begin{aligned}
U_n(\cos t)&=\frac{\sin (n+1)t}{\sin t},\\
U_n(\cosh t)&=\frac{\sinh (n+1)t}{\sinh t}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Using the second of these, we let $\cosh t=\frac{5}{4}$ and find that $e^t=\frac{1}{2}$ or $2$.  Choosing one of these solutions, say $e^t=2$, one can evaluate both $\sinh (n+1)t$ and $\sinh t$.  The end result is the given formula.

This works for general $x,$ but as noted in Marc van Leeuwen's comment to user17762's answer, special care is required when $x=\pm1.$  Solving $\cosh t=x$ or $e^t+e^{-t}=2x$ we find $e^t=x\pm\sqrt{x^2-1},$ which yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
U_n(x)=U_n(\cosh t)&=\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^{n+1}-(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^{n+1}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}-(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})}\\
&=\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^{n+1}-(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^{n+1}}{2\sqrt{x^2-1}}.
\end{aligned}
$$
This clearly reduces to a polynomial in $x,$ but is more useful than the polynomial form for evaluation.  When $x=\pm1,$ which is equivalent to $t=im\pi,$ l'Hôpital's rule is needed in the evaluation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
U_n(\pm1)=U_n(\cosh im\pi)&=\lim_{t\to im\pi}\frac{e^{(n+1)t}-e^{-(n+1)t}}{e^t-e^{-t}}\\
&=\lim_{t\to im\pi}\frac{(n+1)e^{(n+1)t}+(n+1)e^{-(n+1)t}}{e^t+e^{-t}}=(n+1)(\pm1)^n.
\end{aligned}
$$

**Revised question:** The method can be adapted to handle the more general form in the revised question of February 2015.  If $bc=0$ the determinant is clearly $a^n.$  Otherwise, let $g$ be a solution to $g^2=bc$ and define $x:=\frac{a}{2g},$ $y:=\frac{b}{g}.$  Since $\frac{c}{g}=\frac{g}{b}=y^{-1},$ the more general determinant is equal to
$$
g^n\det\begin{bmatrix}2x & y & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ y^{-1} & 2x & y & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 0 & y^{-1} & 2x & y & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &\vdots\\ 0 & 
\cdots & 0 & y^{-1} & 2x & y & 0\\ 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & y^{-1} & 2x & y\\ 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & y^{-1} & 2x\end{bmatrix}=:g^nD_n(x,y).
$$
But $D_n(x,y)$ satisfies the same recurrence as $D_n(x)$ and the same initial conditions, and so $D_n(x,y)$ also equals $U_n(x).$  (It is independent of $y.$)

Answer (score 4):

The determinant can also be verified using [block determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices).

Define $A^{(k)}$ to be the $k\times k$ matrix of the form$$A^{(k)}:=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        5 & 2 & 0 &0&0&\cdots & 0\\
        2 & 5 & 2 & 0&0&\cdots & 0\\
        0 & 2 &5&2&0 & \cdots & 0\\
        \vdots & \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \vdots\\
        0 & \cdots& & 0& 2 &5& 2\\
        0 & \cdots & & \cdots&\cdots& 2 &5
        \end{bmatrix}.
$$
This can be expressed as
$$A^{(k)}=\begin{bmatrix}A^{(k-1)}&u\\u^T&5\end{bmatrix},$$
where $u=[0,0,0,\ldots,2]^T$ is a $k\times1$ vector.

It follows form the block determinant form that
$$
\det\left(A^{(k)}\right)=\det\left(A^{(k-1)}\right)\det\left(5-u^T{\left(A^{(k-1)}\right)}^{-1}u\right),
$$
which can be simplified dramatically by the structure of $u$ as
$$
\det\left(A^{(k)}\right)=\det\left(A^{(k-1)}\right)\left(5-4{\left(A^{(k-1)}\right)}^{-1}_{n,n}\right).
$$
Furthermore,
$$\left(A^{(k-1)}\right)^{-1}_{n,n}=\frac{(-1)^{n+n}\det\left(A^{(k-2)}\right)}{\det\left(A^{(k-1)}\right)}=\frac{\det\left(A^{(k-2)}\right)}{\det\left(A^{(k-1)}\right)}.$$
The recurrence relation for the determinant can then be written as, upon simplifying,
$$\det\left(A^{(k)}\right)=5\det\left(A^{(k-1)}\right)-4\det\left(A^{(k-2)}\right),$$
from which the required form of the determinant can be verified similarly to the previous answers.

Answer (score 3):

For the more general case of a tridiagonal [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) mentioned at the end on the question, the direct method (not using induction) I used in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1148960/18880)  can be adopted as follows. First note that the answer will depend only on $a$ and the product $p=bc$, since conjugation by a diagonal matrix with as diagonal entries a geometric progression $1,t,t^2,\ldots,t^{n-1}$ can be used to move any nonzero factor$~t$ from $b$ to $c$. If $p=0$ then we have a triangular matrix, and the determinant will be $a^n$; with this trivial case put aside, I can therefore assume (for reasons to become clear) without loss of generality that $c=-1$. So we want to know
$$
 D=
  \begin{vmatrix} a & -p & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ -1 & a & -p & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 0 & -1 & a & -p & \ddots & 0\\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & -1 & a & -p\\ 0 & 0  & \cdots &0 & -1 & a \end{vmatrix}.  
$$

The quadratic polynomial $X^2-aX+p$ will be of importance; let $r$ be a root of this polynomial. Multiplying our matrix from the left by
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}1&r&r^2&\ldots&\ldots&r^{n-1}\\
                0&1&r&r^2&\ddots&r^{n-2}\\
                0&0&1&r&\ddots&r^{n-3}\\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 1& \ddots & \vdots \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots& \ddots & r \\
                0&0& \ldots& \ldots &0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix},
$$
which has determinant$~1$, gives due to the fact that $-r^2+ar-p=0$ (and so $ar-p=r^2$), the matrix
$$
R=\begin{pmatrix}a-r&0&0&\ldots&0&r^n\\
 -1&a-r&0&\ddots&0&r^{n-1}\\
0&-1&a-r&\ddots&0&r^{n-2}\\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots&\vdots \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & -1 & a-r& r^2 \\
  0&0& \ldots &0&-1 & a
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
The diagonal entries are equal to the other root $s=a-r$ of $X^2-aX+p$ (possibly equal to$~r$), except for the last entry which is $s+r$.

Now one can recognise that $C=sI-C_P$ where $C_P$ is the companion matrix of
$$
  P=r^n+r^{n-1}X+r^{n-2}X^2+\cdots+r^2X^{n-2}+rX^{n-1}+X^n.
$$
Since $C_P$ has as characteristic polynomial $\det(IX-C_P)=P$, we get as our determinant
$$
  \det(R)=P[X:=s]=r^n+r^{n-1}s+r^{n-2}s^2+\cdots+r^2s^{n-2}+rs^{n-1}+s^n.
$$
So our answer can be written as
$$
  D=\det(R) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{r^{n+1}-s^{n+1}}{r-s}&\text{if }r\neq s,\\ \\
\displaystyle                  (n+1)r^n&\text{if }r=s.\end{cases}
$$
Of course one can take by the quadratic formula concretely $r=\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-4p}}2$ and  $s=\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-4p}}2$, but this does not make the answer more transparent.