# Determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix with 5's on the diagonal and 2's on the superdiagonal and subdiagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Special determinant formula for a specific matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266998/special-determinant-formula-for-a-specific-matrix)

How to find $\det A_n$ as a function of $n$?

$$A_n=\begin{pmatrix} 5&2 &0& 0  & \ldots &  0\\
2& 5& 2& 0 & \ldots &   0\\
0 &2& 5 &2  & \ldots &  0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  &   \vdots\\
0 &0& 0& 0 & \ldots &   5\end{pmatrix}$$

I tried to develop Laplace and mathematical induction, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Try using method of minors for n = 1, n = 2, n = 3, n= 4, you will find something.

Comment: After you discover the pattern you can use induction then

Comment: A note : if one expansion by minors fails, do not be discouraged. The solution I know to this requires more than just a single expansion by minors for the inductive step.

Comment: Exact same as [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266998/special-determinant-formula-for-a-specific-matrix/267000#267000)

Answer (score 5):

Example:
$$
\left|\begin{matrix}
5&2&0&0\\
2&5&2&0\\
0&2&5&2\\
0&0&2&5
\end{matrix}\right|
=5\left|\begin{matrix}
5&2&0\\
2&5&2\\
0&2&5
\end{matrix}\right|
-2\left|\begin{matrix}
2&2&0\\
0&5&2\\
0&2&5
\end{matrix}\right|
=5\left|\begin{matrix}
5&2&0\\
2&5&2\\
0&2&5
\end{matrix}\right|
-2^2\left|\begin{matrix}
5&2\\
2&5
\end{matrix}\right|.
$$
The first equality is obtained by Laplace expansion along the first row, while the second one is obtained by Laplace expansion along the first column. So you get a recurrence relation.

Comment: If you don't know how to solve the recurrence relation, check here: http://www.wikihow.com/Solve-Recurrence-Relations under ''Linear''. Concise and simple.

Comment: have $5(An-1) - 4(An-2) A1=5, A2=21, A3=85 $ but the recurrence is so hard.

Comment: @aiki93 Have you looked at the webpage mentioned by ante.ceperic in the previous comment? The recurrence relation is $A_n = 5A_{n-1} - 4A_{n-2}$. Its characteristic equation is $x^2-5x+4=0$. Solve it to get two roots $y$ and $z$. The general solution is then $A_n = by^n + cz^n$, where $b$ and $c$ are some constants. Put $A_1=5,\,A_2=21$, you can determine $b$ and $c$. You do need to take a little work, but the recurrence relation is by no means hard to solve.