# What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this circulant tridiagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, circulant-matrices

\begin{equation}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \alpha & \beta & 0  & \dots & 0  & 0      & \beta \\
        \beta & \alpha & \beta  & \dots & 0  & 0      & 0 \\
  0  & \beta & \alpha & \dots & 0  & 0      & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & \alpha & \beta      & 0 \\
  0      & 0      & 0  & \dots & \beta & \alpha & \beta \\
        \beta      & 0      & 0  & \dots & 0 & \beta  & \alpha
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

What is the closed-form solution for this circulant tridiagonal matrix?

Comment: Neither tridiagonal nor Toeplitz. It's circulant. The eigenvalues are related to the Discrete Fourier Transform.

Comment: Thx, can you give more details?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues

Comment: https://ee.stanford.edu/~gray/toeplitz.html

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo, thx for your note, but I still don't know how to implement the circulant matrix with DFT. Can you give a detailed example?

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477418/finding-eigenvalues-in-almost-tridiagonal-matrix