# Determinants of symmetric tridiagonal matrix after removing first row and column

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The symmetric traditional matrix $A$ and its determinant is given.

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
 a_1&b_1&0&0&0&0& \cdots &0\\
 b_1&a_2&b_2&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
 0&b_2&a_3&b_3&0&0&\cdots&0\\
 0&0&b_3&a_4&b_4&0&\cdots&0\\
 0&0&0&b_4&a_5&b_5&\cdots&0\\
 0&0&0&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
 0&0&0&0&0&b_{n-2}&a_{n-1}&b_{n-1}\\
 0&0&0&0&0&0&b_{n-1}&a_n\\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

What is the determinant of matrix $B$ which exactly $A$ after removing first row and column?

$$ B = \begin{bmatrix}
 a_2&b_2&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
 b_2&a_3&b_3&0&0&\cdots&0\\
 0&b_3&a_4&b_4&0&\cdots&0\\
 0&0&b_4&a_5&b_5&\cdots&0\\
 0&0&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
 0&0&0&0&b_{n-2}&a_{n-1}&b_{n-1}\\
 0&0&0&0&0&b_{n-1}&a_n\\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Is there any known way to calculate this from $A$?

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can only find by [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion):

$$det A=a_1\cdot detB-b_1\cdot detB'$$

and

$$det B'=b_1\cdot detC-b_2\cdot detC'$$

and so on, but it seems not possible to simplify further.

Comment: what is $B'$? the $B$ transpose?

Comment: sorry for the notation, B' is the matrix you obtain from A eliminating the firs row and the second column accordin to Laplace expansion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion

Comment: From [This question][1] We know for a tridiagonal matrix the following recursion relation is true (notations described in there) $$f_i = d_if_{i-1} - c_ia_{i-1}f_{i-2}$$ 

Won't this help?
  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575748/determinant-of-symmetric-tridiagonal-matrices

Comment: @Drupalist It seems to confirm that in general it is not possible to simplify further