# How to find the eigenvalues of the following tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, tridiagonal-matrices

The $n$-order tridiagonal matrix is defined by $A(i,i)=0, A(i,i+1)=n-i, A(i+1,i)=i$, i.e.,

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&n-1\\1&0&n-2\\&2&0&n-3\\&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\&&&n-2&0&1\\&&&&n-1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

All eigenvalues of $A$ are $-(n-1),-(n-3),\ldots,(n-3),(n-1)$, however, I could not figure out a simple way to show that.

Comment: I have some observations, e.g., $n-1$ is the eigenvalue; and if $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue, then $-\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue. However, I think these two observations do not help so much...

Comment: Try reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266998/how-to-compute-the-determinant-of-a-tridiagonal-matrix-with-constant-diagonals).

Comment: Thanks Peter. But I think this page discussed the tridiagonal with the constant number? There is a page discussing [non-constant case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575748/determinant-of-symmetric-tridiagonal-matrices), but there are no useful conclusion. Also, I think calculating the determinant is not enough to show all the eigen values?

Comment: Using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuant_(mathematics)) generalization you can compute the determinant for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and since eigenvalues are roots of the characteristic polynomial - which is defined as $ \det (A - \lambda \mathbb{I}_{n} )$ - you can then compute them form it.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but it is also costly with lots of calculations. In fact, an easier method is to construct the eigenvector given the eigenvalue (which should be faster because each component of the eigenvector can be solved one by one immediately). But I think both are not elegant compared with the simple form of the eigenvalues.

Comment: That's a Sylvester-Kac matrix pretty known in the litterature.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it! Here is a good [survey](https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/ijnsns/21/3-4/article-p361.xml) of this matrix.