# Determinant evaluation for matrix with $-1, 2, -1$ below/on/above diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

What is the trick for evaluating the determinant of this matrix?

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
& -1 & 2 & -1 \\
&& -1 & 2 & -1 \\
&&& -1 & 2 & -1 \\
&&&& -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: What do you mean to evaluate it?

Comment: Determinate? What do you mean by evaluate?

Comment: there is a three term recursive formula. you can look up the determinant of a tridiagonal matrix.

Comment: Apologies. Question updated.

Comment: This is not just any tridiagonal matrix, it's a very special one. I think we can find a basis of eigenvectors analytically. The $j$th component of eigenvector $m$ is something like $\sin(m \pi j/N) $. Knowing the eigenvalues, we get the determinant.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995779/proving-the-determinant-of-a-tridiagonal-matrix

Comment: Elaborating on my previous comment: it's useful to know that the $m$th eigenvector of this $N \times N$ matrix is the vector whose $j$th component is $\sin(m \pi j/(N+1))$.  This can be checked by a direct calculation, which reveals that the corresponding eigenvalue is $2 - 2 \cos(m \pi/(N+1))$.  One could then show that the product of the eigenvalues is $N+1$.  This isn't as simple as the answer given, but sometimes it's useful to know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: For a more general version, see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266998/special-determinant-formula-for-a-specific-matrix/267466#267466).

Answer (score 6):

let $f_n$ be the the determinant of the $n \times n$ tridiagonal matrix with diagonal elements all equal to $2$ and the sub and super diagonal has $-1$ on them.
then by expanding the determinant by the first row, you get the recursive relation $$f_n = 2f_{n-1} - f_{n-2},\quad f_1 = 2,\ f_2 = 3.$$ you can verify that $$f_n = n+1$$ is in fact the solution.