# A pattern among the singular values of a matrix with a pattern

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148581/matrix-evaluation-trick) asked for an intelligent way to find
$$
\det \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
& -1 & 2 & -1 \\
&& -1 & 2 & -1 \\
&&& -1 & 2 & -1 \\
&&&& -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
I did not attempt to answer it, but I ran a few things through R, and found the singular values:
$$
3.8019377,\quad 3.2469796,\quad  2.4450419,\quad  1.5549581,\quad  0.7530204,\quad  0.1980623
$$
When I plotted these on the $y$-axis with the sequence $1,2,3,4,5,6$ on the $x$-axis, I thought they were in a straight line, and a second later I thought that they were not.  So I fitted the least-squares line and put $1,2,3,4,5,6$ on the $x$-axis and the residuals on the $y$-axis, and saw something.  The residuals are:
$$
-0.08315789,\quad 0.11592223,\quad 0.06802274,\quad -0.06802274,\quad -0.11592223,\quad 0.08315789
$$
The $k$th residual is $-1$ times the $(7-k)$th residual.  Why is that?

(At least some of this is to be expected: the sum of all six residuals must be $0$ and their linear combination with coefficients $1,2,3,4,5,6$ must be $0$; we know that much before knowing anything about the six $y$ values.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues of a sign-symmetric $n\times n$ tridiagonal matrix $\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&\ddots&\ddots\\&\ddots&\ddots}$ with constant diagonals are given by $a+2\sqrt{bc}\cos\frac{k\pi}{n+1}$ with $k=1,2,\ldots,n$ (see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955168/how-to-prove-the-eigenvalues-of-tridiagonal-matrix), for instance). So, the residuals from linear regression are given by the cosine function. Hence your observation.