# Find determinant of given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be an $n × n$ matrix of the following form.

[image]

What is the value of the determinant of $A$?

1. [image: List item]
2. [image: List item]
3. [image: List item]
4. [image: List item]

---

My attempt:

I've used brute force to identity correct option.
When I put $n=1$, then determinant of $A$ should be and options give $5, 7, 3, 3$ respectively. Since, options $(3)$ and $(4)$ return same value.

So, I put $n=2$, then determinant of $A$ should be $8$  and option $(3)$ and $(4)$ return $7$ and $8$ respectively. So, option $(4)$ is correct.

> Can you explain in formal way? Please.

Comment: Check [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995779/proving-the-determinant-of-a-tridiagonal-matrix-with-1-2-1-on-diagonal).

Comment: @Solitary, thanks for reference. Just, I need a solution for given options if you don't mind, please.

Comment: Solutions are there, just replace the 2 there by 3, -1 there by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A_n$ be the matrix of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
3&1&&&&&\\
1&3&1&&&&\\
&1&3&1&&&\\
&&1&3&&&\\
&&&&\ddots\\
&&&&&3&1\\
&&&&&1&3
\end{bmatrix}_{n\times n}\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Then by Solitary' comment, we have $\det A_1=3$, $\det A_2=8$, and for
$n\ge 3$,
$$\det A_n=3\det A_{n-1}-\det A_{n-2}.$$
Let $a_n=\det A_n$, and define $B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&3\end{bmatrix}$
and ${\bf x}_n=\begin{bmatrix}a_{n}\\a_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}$. Then the original pattern of the sequence becomes
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{n+1}\\a_{n+2}\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_{n}\\a_{n+1}\end{bmatrix},\quad n\ge 1.$$
That is,
\begin{align}
{\bf x}_{n+1}=
B{\bf x}_n \quad \mbox{for all }n\ge 1,\quad\mbox{with }{\bf x}_1=\begin{bmatrix}3\\8\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
It follows that ${\bf x}_{n+1}=B^n{\bf x}_1$, and we need to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $B$ as below. By a little computation, the eigenvalues are
$$\lambda_1=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\lambda_2=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$
The corresponding eigenvectors are
$${\bf v}_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\ \lambda_1\end{bmatrix}\quad\mbox{and}\quad
{\bf v}_2=\begin{bmatrix}1\\ \lambda_2\end{bmatrix}.$$
Let $P=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\ \lambda_1&\lambda_2\end{bmatrix}$, then 
$P^{-1}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{5}}
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_2&-1\\ -\lambda_1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and
$$B=P\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}.$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
{\bf x}_{n+1}
&=B^n{\bf x}_1\\
&=P\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1^n&0\\0&\lambda_2^n\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}3\\8\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}\ast\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}[\lambda_1^{n+1}(8-3\lambda_2)+\lambda_2^{n+1}(3\lambda_1-8)]\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\det A 
&=\det A_n=a_n\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\lambda_1^{n-1}(8-3\lambda_2)
+\lambda_2^{n-1}(3\lambda_1-8)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n-1}\left(
\frac{3\sqrt{5}+7}{2}\right)
+\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt{5}-7}{2}\right)\right].
\end{align}
Hence the answer is 4.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: You are welcome! This is a classical problem about diagonalization of a matrix. :)