# Doubt in a concept while finding the determinant of a tridiagonal matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

I was going through the second answer of this question but I can't understand if it is correct to expand the determinant along the column 1st and then in the recursive step to compute the determinant along the row?

[Proving the determinant of a tridiagonal matrix with $-1, 2, -1$ on diagonal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995779/proving-the-determinant-of-a-tridiagonal-matrix-with-1-2-1-on-diagonal)

How do I compute the determinant of a tridiagonal matrix. I was going through the 1st answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571038/determinant-of-tridiagonal-matrix) and there I saw that $\det(\Delta_n))=a_n\Delta_{n-1}-bc\Delta_{n-2}$ .I am unable to understand how are we getting $-bc\Delta_{n-2}$  - is the expansion along the row or the column? I need some help or an explicit answer as I have been stuck with these types of matrices for a long time.