# How do I find the determinants of $n\times n$ matrix here?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have inclination for find the general form of determinant for the provided matrix that I have shown in the following picture. As you can see, I drive the determinant for 3×3 , 4×4 up to the order of 8×8. Interestingly, it seems like that it follows a specific pattern and I want to find it. I would be immensely appreciative if you can lend me a hand on this matter.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy7io.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Also, there are many posts here, which have already discussed this. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571038/determinant-of-tridiagonal-matrix), or  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266998/how-to-compute-the-determinant-of-a-tridiagonal-matrix-with-constant-diagonals).