# Determinant of the following n×n matrix:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Determinant of the following $n \times n$ matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2\cos \theta& 1 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 \\
1 & 2\cos \theta & 1 & \ddots & & \vdots \\
0 & 1& 2\cos \theta & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0  \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \ddots & 2\cos \theta & 1 \\
0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & 1 & 2\cos \theta\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Letting given matrix determinant as $D_n$, I find a relation $D_n-2\cos \theta D_{n-1}+D_{n-2}=0$, but after that how  I calculate $D_n?$ Please help.

Comment: You should solve the equation $\lambda^2 - 2 \cos \theta \lambda + 1 = 0$ find $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ and then your solution will be $D_n = C_1 \lambda_1^n + C_2 \lambda_2^n, $ $\ C_1, C_2$ you should find from initial conditions

Comment: @DF ... assuming $\cos\theta\ne1$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli of course, if $\cos \theta = 1$ then $D_n = (C_1 + C_2 n)$

Comment: but roots are complex here...

Comment: In the reference given by @Hans Lundmark, look directly to the answer by "user17762".

Comment: Using the [general formula for the tridiagonal determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/267466/122782)
it is straightforward to get
$\det{D_n}=\frac{\sin((n+1)\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$.