# Simple matrix determinant expression

Tags: determinant

I'm currently resolving a problem, and I came across the following matrix for which I need an expression of the determinant.
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    a+1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & . & . & . & 1 & 1 \\
    -a & a+1 & 1 & 1 & . & . & . & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & -a & a+1 & 1 & . & . & . & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & -a & a+1 & . &  &  & . & . \\
    . & . & . & . & . & . &  & . & . \\
    . & . &  & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
    . & . &  &  & . & . & . & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & . & . & . & 0 & -a & a+1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & . & . & . & . & 0 & -a & a+1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
where $a$ is a real number.
This matrix can also be described like this:

$$
m_{i, j} = 
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $i<j$} \\
a+1, & \text{if $i=j$} \\
-a, & \text{if $i=j+1$} \\
0, & \text{if $i>j+1$}
\end{cases}
$$

The size of the matrix is not known, potentially high (more than 1000).

I do not know how to solve this problem, nor can it be solved.

**Edit:**

Following achille hui advice, the problem is equivalent to compute an expression of the determinant of the next matrix:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    2a+1 & -a & 0 & . & . & . & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    -a & 2a+1 & -a & . & . & . & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -a & 2a+1 & . & . & . & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    . & . & . & . & . &  &  & . & . \\
    . & . & . & . & . & . &  & . & . \\
    . & . &  & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
    0 & 0 & 0 &  & . & . & 2a+1 & -a & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & . & . & . & -a & 2a+1 & -a \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & . & . & . & 0 & -a & a+1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
Be aware that the last coefficient is  $a+1$ and not $2a+1$.

**Edit 2:**

By developping the last row, we get ride of the last coefficient and we deal with tridiagonal matrices with constant diagonals.

Using the answer from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266998/how-to-compute-the-determinant-of-a-tridiagonal-matrix-with-constant-diagonals), we get the following expression:
$$
det_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4a+1}} \biggl[ \frac{1+\sqrt{4a+1}}{2} \biggl(\frac{2a+1+\sqrt{4a+1}}{2}\biggl)^n - \frac{1-\sqrt{4a+1}}{2} \biggl(\frac{2a+1-\sqrt{4a+1}}{2}\biggl)^n \biggl]
$$

Comment: Subtract 2nd row from 1st row, Subtract 3rd row from 2nd row and so on... You will get a tridigonal matrix and you can setup a recurrence relation for the determinant....